# Is it unsecure to use $_GET to update the data from database?

Tags: php, get, xss, security

Is it unsecure to use $_GET to update/delete the data from MySQL table??

I can't use $_POST since it required to use `<form>` tag

For example:

```
  <a href="status.php?approve='123'>Unapprove</a>
 <?php   
    if (isLoggedIn() && groupId() == 2) {
     if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) {
      $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE table set unapprove='1' where id = :id");
      $query->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $query->execute();
     }
    }
?>
```

Please provide example how would you secure from my example or better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not subject to SQL injections, what you're doing is not secure because subject to [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Consider the effect of being logged in into your site, and visiting another that has this image:

```
<img src="yoursite.com/admin/status.php?approve=123" />
```

Ideally, always use POST for non-idempotent requests.

And at any rate, you need to add a secret token which is both session- and link-specific:

```
href="status.php?approve=123&amp;token=[random_stuff]"
```

As an aside, the `'123'` in the link should probably be `123`.

Comment: They might visit a site which submits a form using JavaScript. Using POST doesn't protect against CSRF, that's a different issue.

Comment: How can user access to <img src= because those tags will not be on the page? also what is the problem with <img src="yoursite.com/admin/status.php?approve=123" /> ? what can it harm?

Comment: @user the `img` link will cause a request to that URL, causing the item to be approved (or deleted, or whatever) - possibly without the user's knowledge.

Comment: If I put that image on my own site, and you're logged in on your site, it will fire up the action exactly as if you had visited it by opening the page in your browser.

Comment: @Pekka , @Denis Ahh understandable..  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't safe.

All it takes is for a bot, or a pre-caching proxy, etc to come along and follow all the links (which are supposed to be safe to follow) and you'll get everything unapproved automatically.

Use a `<form>`.

Comment: @Matty — They can, but benign ones don't. A harmless search engine indexer will follow links.

Comment: @GolexTroi — a user with a pre-caching proxy might be though. When Google added that feature to Google Desktop, a lot of forums found their content wiped out because admins were using it.

Comment: To use $_POST - in that case - will have to remove the href and replace to input button? What about $.post() from jquery?

Comment: @Quentin "Harmless" (well, honest) ones also respect robots.txt, but that's not the issue. There are plenty of ways using authentication/permissions to prevent bots from doing bad things.

Comment: @user622378 — form and submit button is the simple option. Using JavaScript would violate progressive enhancement principles.

Comment: @Matty — robots.txt shouldn't be used as a hack to work around improper use of HTTP. And a bot might be authorised (for some reason or another, e.g. a user wants to scrape some content for reading off-line).

Answer (score 1):

It's not insecure per-se, so long as you validate and sanitize input. Input is input, but remember, all input is evil. Think about permissions too. How are you controlling access to this?

Bounds check the numeric data. From the code above it's possible to insert numbers that are likely out of range.

Also, as a matter of good practice, I always pass everything through `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (or the OOP equivalent if you so wish.)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter for your database if you use $_GET or $_POST, and it is not unsecure because you're checking if the user is logged in. It is unsafe however. A logged in user can have the delete-url in his browsing history, which may cause resources to be deleted when they visit that page later on by accidentally choosing them in their history.

It is better to post this kind of data.

If you like to, you can create forms instead of links. You can style the submit buttons so that they look like links. Per link you create a form. That way, you'll have the same functionality and looks, even without Javascript, and you still have the relative safety of posting in contrast to getting.